# Change terminal text color for next command only

Tags: command-line, terminal, colors

So when I find myself compiling a lot (from the terminal) I find it difficult to distinguish between the current compilation results and the old ones, so I was wondering if there is a bit of text that I can input in the command to make the output text of that command a different color (like green or red or blue).

For example instead of running just

```
gcc something.c
```

I want to run something like

```
gcc something.c textcolor=green
```

and the color of the output would be green, but for the next one, it would be back to the default color.

Comment: Your last sentence was incomprehensible. Did you expect that if you run `gcc something.c` again then the output of the *first* run turns from green to white? If so, this isn't practical, no. Why not clear the terminal before a new compilation?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using terminal escapes; `tput` is handy.

```
tput setaf 2; gcc something.c; tput sgr0 # 2 is color code for green
```

This will interact unpredictably with anything else that changes the console colors, including the makefiles produced by some tools.

Comment: You can save typing the trailing `tput sgr0` every time by placing it at the beginning of your prompt (e.g. `PS1=$'\\[\E[m\\] <the rest goes here>'`).

Comment: And by setting up a couple of aliases, you could simply type `green; gcc something.c`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to set up a prompt that is visually distinctive. My one is something along these lines (it's bold, italic, and a gold-ish color (256-color support required)):

`PS1=$'\\[\E[0;1;3;38;5;136m\\]blahblah$ \\[\E[m\\]'`

Also, when I'm re-running a command that produced lots of output and the new run is also expected to produce a lot, I usually press several lone Enters at the prompt before re-running it. It's much easier to locate that "gap" when looking back.